# React Native setState in componentDidMount does not work

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to `setSate` in `componentDidMount()` but the state isn't getting changed. I declared the states as below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      links: [],
      personalInfo: {
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        address: {
          city: "",
          state: "",
          country: "",
        },
      },

      statement: "",
      editMode: false,
      superEditMode: false,
    }
  }
```

And my componentDidMount is as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      this.props.data.personalInfo ? this.setState({personalInfo: this.props.data.personalInfo}) : null
      this.props.data.address ? this.setState({address: this.props.data.address}) : null

      //this.props.data.links ? this.setState({links: this.props.data.links}) : null
      //console.log((this.props.data.links ? true : false));
      this.setState({links: [
        {
          linkType: "Portfolio",
          linkAddress: "www.johndoe.com",
        },
        {
          linkType: "Github",
          linkAddress: "https://github.com/johndoe",
        },
        {
          linkType: "LinkedIn",
          linkAddress: "https://linkedin.com/johndoe",
        },
      ]});
      console.log(this.state.links);
      this.props.data.statement ? this.setState({statement: this.props.data.statement}) : null
    }
```

It is very strange that `this.state.personalInfo` `this.state.address` `this.state.statement` are being set to the new states from `props` as expected, but `this.state.links` remains to be the initial state.

Comment: setState is async. if you are not seeing on console.log right after its normal. use a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call setState with a state change, you'll force a re-render. So, the first thing I recommend doing is to refactor your code so that you call setState just once...

Second, if you're thinking it's not changing your link state because the `console.log(this.state.links)` is still showing an empty array, that's probably because by the time that line is executed, state hasn't yet been updated. setState is asynchronous. Try this...

```
if (this.props.data) {
    const { personalInfo, address, links, statement } = this.props.data;
    this.setState({
        personalInfo: personalInfo || null,
        address: address || null,
        links: links || null,
        statement: statement || null,
    }, () => {
        const { personalInfo, address, links, statement } = this.state;
        console.log({ personalInfo, address, links, statement });
    })
}
```